# How can I list classes with similar IDs in a list with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have `NodeViewModel` class. There is ID variable in `NodeViewModel` class. It can be two classes but with the same ID variable. IDs are not sequential numbers. Example ID; 010105.

I have a list containing my NodeViewModels as follows;

```
List<NodeViewModel> nodes = new List<NodeViewModel>((IEnumerable<NodeViewModel>)diagram.Nodes);
```

It is necessary to export the information in the content of two matching classes by combining them. Therefore I created a class called `IdNodeInteractionModel`. I want to collect matching NodeViewModels in a List.

```
public class IdNodeInteractionModel
{
    public int ID;
    public NodeViewModel firstNode;
    public NodeViewModel secondNode;
}
```

I can match similar ids with multiple foreach loops. But I am using similar loops. There are if else queries and all of them reduce the readability of the code. How can I make practical readability with Linq?

I would be glad if you help.

Comment: What are _similar_ ids? If you are not meaning equal ids, we need some more information about what are matches and no matches. For example the ids 3, 6, 7 could mean that 6 and 7 make a pair, but what about 3, 5, 7? So please write down the rules with examples to find _similar_ IDs. With this we can provide some sample code.

Comment: Another thoughs about similarity. Given is 3, 5, 7 and the first matching pair is 3,5 and 7 stays alone. What happens if order of items would be 7, 5, 3? Would in that case 5,7 build a pair and 3 stays alone?

Comment: Actually there are 2 NodeViewModels with same id like this. So two 3 ID's, two 5 ID's etc. I want to collect these two same id's in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It can be two classes but with the same ID variable

Sounds like you are looking for [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0)/[`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-7.0). For example:

```cs
List<NodeViewModel> nodes = new List<NodeViewModel>();
var result = nodes
    .GroupBy(n => n.ID)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var pair = g.Take(2).ToArray(); // ignore the rest if we have more then 2
        return new IdNodeInteractionModel
        {
            ID = g.Key,
            FirstNode = pair[0],
            SecondNode = pair.Length > 1 ? pair[1] : null
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I want to add a message in Linq to warn if there are more than 2 of the same ID. How can this be controlled?

Comment: @OzgurSaklanmaz it depends on what you are actually want to do, one way is to update the `Select` lambda, for example by removing the `Take(2)` (or changing it to 3) and checking the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to find *similar* values it is always a good idea to write the logic of determining the *common value* into its own `EqualityComparer<>`. By having this, you can create the needed groups and afterwards project them further into the desired class to hold these information:

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
    .Select(i => new MyNode { Id = i * 5 });

var pairs = values
    .GroupBy(node => node, MyNodeComparer.Default)
    .Select(group => new MyNodePairs
    {
        Id = MyNodeComparer.Default.GetHashCode(group.Key),
        First = group.First(),
        Second = group.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(),
    });


foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Common value: {pair.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"   First:  {pair.First.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"   Second: {pair.Second.Id}");

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The simple models used here are:

```
public class MyNodePairs
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MyNode First { get; set; }
    public MyNode Second { get; set; }
}

public class MyNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the equality comparer to determine the grouping could be something like this:

```
public class MyNodeComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyNode>
{
    public static readonly IEqualityComparer<MyNode> Default = new MyNodeComparer();

    public bool Equals(MyNode? x, MyNode? y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)
            || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        var xSimilar = CalculateCommonValue(x);
        var ySimilar = CalculateCommonValue(y);

        return xSimilar == ySimilar;
    }

    private int CalculateCommonValue([DisallowNull] MyNode source)
    {
        return source.Id / 10;
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] MyNode obj)
    {
        return CalculateCommonValue(obj);
    }
}
```

Be aware that currently it is unhandled that there are less or more elements within a group. Depending on your needs you must add additional checks within the constructor of the pairs.

And here a [working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bmjjoB).

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was an answer with detailed and additional information.